# Fix time issue in oracle

Tags: oracle, time, trim

Table looks like below:

[image]

Expected answer below:
[image]

Write an oracle query to fix space and return hh:mm format. Consider same time in a same group and return total count

Comment: SO is not a homework-writing service.  Please show a little initiatiave by showing your own attempt.  Also, it is impossible to determine the correct query without knowing the data types of the columns in question.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WITH clause in the query below is just for testing; remove it, and use the actual table and column names in the main query. Note: `count` is a reserved keyword, so it can't be a column name. I changed it to `count_` (with an underscore).

```
with
  test_data (srt_tm, count_) as (
    select '1:00'  ,   125 from dual union all
    select '01:00' , 19000 from dual union all
    select ' 01:00',    27 from dual union all
    select '4:00'  , 22000 from dual union all
    select '04:00' ,  1800 from dual union all
    select ' 04:00', 15000 from dual
  )
-- END OF TEST DATA; ACTUAL QUERY BEGINS **BELOW THIS LINE**
select lpad(trim(srt_tm), 5, '0') as srt_tm, sum(count_) as count_
from   test_data
group  by lpad(trim(srt_tm), 5, '0')
order  by srt_tm
;

SRT_TM    COUNT_
------  --------
01:00      19152
04:00      38800
```

Comment: Thanks!!!Yes you are right.I don't have count column.But need count based on SRT_TM on each group

Comment: Can we use regex option for the same case?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. There no reason to use regular expressions, which are much slower, for such a simple problem.

Comment: How to use regexp_replace option here for this same problem. Ask is,use the regexp option. Tried below option                                                                                         select (strt_tm,regexp_replace(strt_tm,'^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$','hh:mm') from test_data where strt_tm ='1:00'